# Covering map with a section induces a group isomorphism between fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-isomorphism, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

> Let $p\colon \tilde{X} \to X$ be a covering map, and $x_0 \in X$. Suppose that there is a section, i.e. a map $s\colon X \to X$ is a map satisfying $p\circ s = \operatorname{id}_X$. Show that $p_*\colon \pi_1(\tilde{X}, s(x_0)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ is an isomorphism.

I have proved that $p_*$ is a group homomorphism. Furthermore, $p\circ s = \operatorname{id}_X$ gives $p_*\circ s_* = \operatorname{id}_{\pi_1(X, x_0)}$, hence $p_*$ is surjective, but I can't show that $p_*$ is injective.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419137/induced-map-between-fundamental-groups-from-covering-map-is-injective

Answer (score 1):

It is true because a covering projection which has a section is a homeomorphism. See [If a covering map has a section, is it a $1$-fold cover?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256951/if-a-covering-map-has-a-section-is-it-a-1-fold-cover/3065651#3065651)

Alternatively you can use the well-known fact that $p_*$ is injective for **each** covering projection. You can find it in any textbook dealing with covering projections.