# Understanding Rotman Algebraic Topology Theorem 10.46

Tags: algebraic-topology

## Definitions and background result

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

## Theorem

[image]

## Question

What exactly is the isomorphism ("via" $p_*$) with $G \cong \pi_1 (\tilde{X}_G, \tilde{x}_0)$?

It cannot be $p_*$ restricted to its image, i.e. $\tilde{p}_* :  \pi_1 (\tilde{X}_G, \tilde{x}_0) \rightarrow G$. This map is not injective in general.

And does this isomorphism always hold for any subgroup G of a fundamental group?

Comment: In fact for a **covering map** $p$, the induced homomorphism between fundamental groups $p_*$ **is** injective if the base space $X$ is nice enough, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419137/induced-map-between-fundamental-groups-from-covering-map-is-injective).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism ***is*** indeed $p_*$, because in the context of Theorems 10.34 and 10.46 the homomorphism $p_*$ ***is*** injective.

Presumably the textbook has already proved that for any covering map $p : \tilde X \to X$ and any $\tilde x \in \tilde X$ and $x=p(\tilde x) \in X$, the induced homomorphism $p_* : \pi_1(\tilde X,\tilde x) \to \pi_1(X,x)$ is injective. The proof usually comes rather early in the theory of covering maps, because it is a straightforward application of the homotopy lifting lemma. Here's a brief sketch. For any closed path $\gamma : [0,1] \to \tilde X$ based at $\tilde x$, the composition $p \circ \gamma : [0,1] \to X$ is a closed path based at $x$. If there exists a path homotopy from $p \circ \gamma$ to the constant path at $x$ then, by applying the homotopy lifting lemma, one obtains a path homotopy from $\gamma$ to the constant path at $\tilde x$. In other words, if $p_*[\gamma]$ is the identity then $[\gamma]$ is the identity. This implies that $p_*$ is injective.

Combined with the conclusion of Theorem 10.34, it follows that $p_* : \pi_1(\tilde X_G,\tilde x_0) \to G$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Mosher, this completely answers my question! Oddly enough, I don't see the proof that $p_*$ is injective in the Covering Maps chapter of Rotman. But I do see that it follows immediately from the Homotoply Lifting Lemma, thanks to your help.